# helm to create single configmap with different labels

Tags: kubernetes-helm, configmap

can anyone help me creating configmaps in helm with different labels.
I have 6 configmaps each have their own labels which will be used by pods. I would like to have the same labels in helm as well. Is it possible in Helm?

These are my values for configmap. I want to render these values and create separate configmap.

```
values.yaml/   
configmaptestingforhelm:
  configmapref1:
        confname: serviceaccount-config
        key: serviceaccount.test.path
        value: /root/test_key.json
  configmapref2:
        confname: host-credentials-config
        key: secret.credentials.host.path
        value: /root/host_key.json
```

I am trying to create separate configmap for each configmappref* as below

```
configmap1
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
{{- range $value := .Values.configmap.configmapref1 }}
metadata:
  name: {{ $value.confname }}
data:
  {{ $value.key }} : {{ $value.value }}
{{- end}}

configmap2
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
{{- range $value := .Values.configmap.configmapref2 }}
metadata:
  name: {{ $value.confname }}
data:
  {{ $value.key }} : {{ $value.value }}
{{- end}}
```

My expected output is as below ,but I am not getting the desired output

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  secret.credentials.host.path: /root/host_key.json
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: host-credentials-config

apiVersion: v1
data:
  serviceaccount.test.path: /root/test_key.json
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: serviceaccount-config
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

values.yaml

```yaml
testLables:
  cm0:
    a: b
    c: d
  cm1:
    e: f
    g: k
```

templates/configmap.yaml

```yaml
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: {{ include "test.fullname" . }}-0
  labels:
    {{- include "test.labels" . | nindent 4 }}
    {{- range $k, $v := .Values.testLables.cm0 }}
    {{ $k }}: {{ $v }}
    {{- end }}
data: 
  data: |-
    k: v

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: {{ include "test.fullname" . }}-1
  labels:
    {{- include "test.labels" . | nindent 4 }}
    {{- range $k, $v := .Values.testLables.cm1 }}
    {{ $k }}: {{ $v }}
    {{- end }}
data: 
  data: |-
    k: v
```

cmd:

```bash
helm template --debug test .
```

output

```yaml
---
# Source: test/templates/configmap.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: test-0
  labels:
    helm.sh/chart: test-0.1.0
    app.kubernetes.io/name: test
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: test
    app.kubernetes.io/version: "1.18.0"
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    a: b
    c: d
data: 
  data: |-
    k: v
---
# Source: test/templates/configmap.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: test-1
  labels:
    helm.sh/chart: test-0.1.0
    app.kubernetes.io/name: test
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: test
    app.kubernetes.io/version: "1.18.0"
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    e: f
    g: k
data: 
  data: |-
    k: v
```

---

update:

values.yaml

```yaml
configmaptestingforhelm:
  configmapref1:
    confname: serviceaccount-config
    key: serviceaccount.test.path
    value: /root/test_key.json
  configmapref2:
    confname: host-credentials-config
    key: secret.credentials.host.path
    value: /root/host_key.json
```

templates/configmap.yaml

```yaml
{{- range $k, $cm := .Values.configmaptestingforhelm }}
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: {{ $cm.confname }}
data: 
  {{ $cm.key }}: {{ $cm.value }}
{{- end }}
```

cmd

```bash
helm template --debug test .
```

output:

```yaml
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: serviceaccount-config
data: 
  serviceaccount.test.path: /root/test_key.json
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: host-credentials-config
data: 
  secret.credentials.host.path: /root/host_key.json
```

Comment: Well to be more précised i am looking to deploy confimaps which are already present. I want to bundle it up in helm and deploy them when i run helm "helm chart". like below I have 6 configmaps with different metadata name  and key value pair. I want them to be deployed in helm 
apiVersion: v1
data:
  secret.projectid.host: "my some value "
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: host-projectid-config

Comment: May you provide more detailed information including the relevant values.yaml, template/configmap.yaml and what output you expect.

Comment: I have updated values and configmap in question. Let me know if that helps you.

Comment: I have updated too.

Comment: This worked. thanks a lot for you help. Highly apricated